# Insertar fecha a una imagen al ser seleccionada o tomada por cámara

Tags: php, javascript, html

No logro encontrar un método para eso, necesito que me ayuden que al tomar una foto o al buscarla en el dispositivo al momento de mostrarla en pantalla ya tenga como marca de agua la fecha.

Comment: bucarla en el dispositivo? con que lenguaje estas desarrollando? que es app? o un sistema en web?

Comment: Me lo pidieron en html y php, es un sistema en web.

Comment: Tienes que subirla al servidor de forma habitual y en el momento de almacenarla añadir la marca de agua. Cuando tengas el código de eso, si te falla, edita y pregunta cuestiones concretas (si te funciona responde tu mismo que seguro que le vale a alguien más). Para la marca de agua: http://php.net/manual/es/image.examples.merged-watermark.php

Comment: Gracias, ya habia leido esa informacion, pero no es lo que busco, no sé si no fui especifico, quiero que al seleccionar una imagen me salga con marca de agua en texto(cualquier texto).